# Shopify Liquid Theme advance custom field checkbox if-statement did not understand "true" as truthy

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have added a few checkboxes to my products in Shopify via the Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

In the theme I would like to iterate through these checkboxes and only if the checkbox has been checked do I want to display a specific translation text here.

However, I fail on the IF statement to check whether the checkbox is checked or not.

Here is my code (with some debugging output)

```
<ul>
  {% for field in product.metafields.warnhinweise %}
    {% assign field_first = field | first %}
    {% assign field_last = field | last %}
    <li>ID: {{ field_first }} - Value: {{ field_last }}</li>

    {% assign language_key = 'products.productwarnings.' | append: field_first %}

      {% if field_last == true %}
        <ul>
          <li>ID: {{ field_first }} - Value: {{ field_last }}</li>
          <ul>
            <li>nest the variable output: {{ language_key  | t }}</li>
          </ul>
        </ul>
      {% else %}
        <ul>
          <li>don't show</li>  
        </ul>
      {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Here is the Output:

[image: As you cann see, no output]

Conclusion: Maybe true is not truthy?

I tried this as well, to check for a string:

```
{% if field_last == 'true' %}
```

But this leads to the same result.

And here is a screenshot from the Advanced Custom Fields backend

[image: Advance Custom Fields Config 1]

Here is the exemplary configuration of a checkbox.

[image: Advance Custom Fields Config 2 - from a Checkbox Item]

I really wonder why such a simple IF statement doesn't work here?

Thanks a lot in Advance for you help.

Comment: Maybe the problem is regarding of the checkbox and the way it gives "true" back? Is it inside an array or something like this?

Comment: If you update your print statement to output `Value: {{ field_last | json }}`, what do you get?  (The `json` filter converts any value to a javascript-legal output, so will show any quotation marks, array brackets, etc. that might be there)

Comment: try stripping your variables for extra white spaces `{% assign field_last = field | last | strip %}`

Comment: Sorry guys for the late reply. @DaveB the Output is now: `Value: ["false"]` or `Value: ["true"]`
@cMarius good idea, but this didn't solve the problem. Fun Fact the output with the json filte is now: `"[\"false\"]"` or `"[\"true\"]"`

Comment: Interesting - it looks like the metafield is being stored as an array that has been converted to a string and is holding the literal value of `["true"]` or `["false"]` (as strings).    What happens if you update your comparison to `{% if field_last contains 'true' %}`?

Comment: Hi @DaveB that’s just amazing! It works! I leave you the honor of phrasing this in response if you like. Otherwise, I'll do it again later in the week. Now I will publish this change in our shop for the first time! You don't even believe how grateful I am to you!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help! Best of luck with your shop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The metafields may not be being stored in a format that exactly matches your comparison

When Shopify prints values to your document, it can sometimes be hard to what the data type of the underlying value was. For example, if `true` is being printed to the document, is that because the value was the boolean `true`, the string `"true"`, an array of values that contains `['true']`, or something else?

To find out what the exact value being used under-the-hood is, I recommend using the `| json` filter to output your variable. By using something like `{{ field_last | json }}`, Shopify will convert the variable into a javascript-legal format and will include all special characters (and some special characters like quotation marks will be escaped by the `\` character), thereby revealing what the underlying structure is.

In your case, it looks like the metafield value is array-like.  Rather than going for an exact match on this construction, I would suggest switching the equality operator (`==`) in your comparison for the `contains` keyword:

```
{% if field_last contains 'true' %}
  <!-- Cool feature goes here! -->
{% endif %}
```